# How to append to existing file

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to redirect the console input to a file. Problem is that every time i create a file it overwrites it or creates new files if I select the name of file to include unix timestamp. I saw similar questions here but I am not sure which approach or class to use.

```
    PrintStream out;
    PrintStream oldout = new PrintStream(System.out);

    try {
        out = new PrintStream(
                new FileOutputStream(
                        workFolder + File.separator + "output" + Instant.now().getEpochSecond() + ".txt"));


         System.setOut(out);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
System.setOut(oldout);
```

So if there isn't a file to create it, but if there is already a file to just append new data, but not overwrite or create new files.

Comment: There's a pretty current guide available at https://www.baeldung.com/java-append-to-file

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[As per Java docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#constructor_detail)

```
public FileOutputStream(String name,
                boolean append)
                 throws FileNotFoundException
```

> Parameters: name - the system-dependent file name
>
> append - if true,
>   then bytes will be written to the end of the file rather than the
>   beginning

There is a constructor which allows passing the boolean value which decides whether to append the data in file or not.

You can use it.